# Transferring data between mongodb and client using node.js

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I have been playing around with some Node.JS examples I found on the web, but I need some help still.

Here is my code: http://pastebin.com/RV7t9fgQ

I want my server to:

- Receive data from the client, to be used in a search query in a MongoDB database.
- When this happens, the server sends results back to the client.

How can I make this happen?

Right now the server does not receive a variable from client.

I cannot test if this works or not, because client cannot import the websocket library due to same origin policy.

I have read this can easily be fixed by making the node.js serve the main html file, how can I implement that in my server?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd recommend using [Express](http://expressjs.com/) for handling requests and serving an HTML file. You have it required but you're not using it. Many people use Express so you'll be in good company and find answers quickly. It's very similar to Socket.io's syntax so your code won't change much.

When you have a basic Express server running you can serve an HTML file that has a search query sending a GET request similar to this:

```
<form action='/search' method='GET'>
    <h2>Search:</h2>
    <input type='search' name='q'>
    <input type='submit'>
</form>
```

And link it with your server like this:

```
var express = require('express'),
    app = express()

app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.send('/path/to/static/page.html')
}

app.get('/search', function(req, res) {
    var query = req.query.q
    db.collection('collection').find(query, function(err, docs) {
        if (err) {
            res.status(500).send(err)
        } else {
            res.send(docs)
        }
    })
})
```

In this example I didn't include how you'd connect to your database as they are many ways to do it. You seem to be using the native MongoDB NodeJS driver which I'm sure can work well, though I use MongoSkin because I found it easier to include into other files.

Comment: Thanks! Main page is now being served but I am getting origin policy errors. Will make another question for that.